# PHP TCPDF Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols not displaying

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, fonts

I am trying to create a pdf with tcpdf and i am facing a problem with the repertoire of "Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols" The characters that appear the most in my documents are U+1D449(0xF0 0x9D 0x91 0x89) and U+1D438 (0xF0 0x9D 0x90 0xB8).

I have checked the font with the FontForge and the glyphs are present in the "freeserif" that comes with the tcpdf. I have checked the codification and i am able to print all other unicode characters even the arabic repertoire.

I have notice a exception on the code of tcpdf to give a special treatment to arabic characters but i was not able to understand the reason behind it.

The characters of this repertoire uses 4 bytes and are displayed correctly on the browser. The files, database and fonts are all on utf-8.

As requested here is a link to the pdf:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mijl7EtNbFRG9Qa1A0Umw0N0E/view?usp=sharing

An image of the problem

[Image of the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgW6q.jpg)

and the piece of code used.

```
$pdf->SetFont('freeserif', '', 18);

$htmlcontent = '<span color="#FF0000">Mathematical Alphanumeric  (̇) -  ' . hex2bin("28F09D9189F09D90B629") . '</span>';

$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlcontent, true, 0, true, 0);
```

To present this i used the example 38 of tcpdf library but i have tried many other codes and examples such as the example 08 and 33.

Comment: You need to bundle the font _inside_ the PDF document.

Comment: All tests were done with the font incorporated ... doesnt work.. Thanks anyway thou!

Comment: Could you please attach an example of such document please? Because to my knowledge this works.

Comment: I have attached an image, piece of code, and the pdf file. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: The issue with such attachments is that they often cannot freely be accessed, as in this case. I can't download that file, sorry.

Comment: Those lines of code reference the font, they certainly do not embed it. Are you _really_ sure it is embedded?

Comment: On properties of the file both FreeSerif and FreeSerif bold are listed as subset  incorporated i also tested with the whole font file and had the same results. If the problem was the embedded font wouldn't be missing all the other unicode characters that are present? If i use any unicode with 3 bytes with my FreeSerif it works perfectly on the file. i have updated the link to the pdf.